# run 2 dos commands using vbScript as a single command

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I am trying to change the directory and then run another command all
in 1 line. But for some strange reason I can't even get the first
command to work. I need help!!
What below code is does, first it launch cmd promt, change directory to directory where my jar file is situated ,that jar file take 3 arguments, all arguments are folder path so it enter java -jar myJar.jar C:\folder1 C:\folder2  C:\folder3

```
dim objShell
dim jarFileFolder, outFile, projFile,folderC ,cmd1,cmd2

'setting variuos paths
 jarFileFolder ="C:\temp\"

 '2 commands
 cmd1= "cd jarFileFolder"
 jarCommand = "java -jar myJar.jar C:\folder1 C:\folder2  C:\folder3"

 set objshell = createobject("Wscript.shell")
 objshell.Run "%compsec% /k cmd1 & jarCommand"

 Below is the link to screenshot of the command i want to execute from vbscript
```

[cmd to be executed from the cmd prompt](http://s14.postimg.org/52lulj97l/Capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first command is that you are not using the jarFileFolder variable, but instead trying to change to a folder named "jarFileFolder". You should try:

```
'setting variuos paths
jarFileFolder ="C:\temp\"

'2 commands
cmd1= "cd " & jarFileFolder
```

And then when you run objShell:

```
set objshell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
objshell.Run "%compsec% /k " & cmd1 & " " & jarCommand
```

Comment: Hi heathesh,i ran it but it showed me the error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: The initial problem with your VBS was that you weren't using the variables correctly, the missing file etc. is because the command you're running doesn't exist. Sorry but I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, I was just trying to help you your syntax.

Comment: Hi heatesh,i already mentioned when i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think `"%compsec% /k " & cmd1 & " " & jarCommand` just needs to be changed to `"%comspec% /k " & cmd1 & " && " & jarCommand`

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this as an answer as I don't have enough rep to comment. You have a typo which might be causing the problem of the command not executing - `compsec` should be `comspec`.